# colorcheme in vim is partially working. how can I apply the theme successfully?

Tags: vimrc, gvim

Thank you for all yours advise that for help to improve my question. I'm not find yet how to resolve this problem in here. I'm really appreciate If you left the link about answer of this problem.

question:
[image]
[image]
[image]

I tried in Window, Linux. (the first picture is gvim editor in window, second picture is vim in Linux, and last picture is example of dark_plus colorscheme )

I copy the source code of dark_plus from [github](https://github.com/dunstontc/vim-vscode-theme/blob/master/colors/dark_plus.vim) and make .vim file in colors directory. And write "colorstheme park_plus" in _vimrc(named .vimrc in Linux), the picture is result what I did. some words looks not applied colorstheme.

Maybe my way not right I think. So I wish your prickly advice how to apply colorstheme and the right way bring the code.

my _vimrc code

```
set autowrite 
set autoindent 
set shiftwidth=4 
set smartindent
set nu 
set incsearch 
set mouse=a 
set guifont=consolas:h11 
set termguicolors 
colorscheme dark_plus
```

version

- vim _ window : 8.2
- vim _ Linux : 8.1

Comment: Welcome to StackExchange!  Your question is hard to follow at the moment.  A few things you could do to improve it:
attach the three screenshots separately, describing each one;
show exactly what you added to your config files (use [code formatting](https://vi.stackexchange.com/editing-help#code), and a link to the github page you copied `dark_plus` from);
say exactly which words are displayed wrongly

Comment: To add to what JigglyNaga said (which is completely correct) also specify which Vim version you are using and in which terminal emulator, as well as if you tried with other terminal emulators to pinpoint where the issue comes from. Also we have tons of similar questions about colorschemes not working properly make sure you read them and try the existing solutions.

Comment: Sounds like you need to `set termguicolor`, provided your terminal supports it.

Comment: Thank you for all your advice! I learned valuable sense today.

Comment: Please note that vim syntax is not always going to be consistent with other editors. That can explain some discrepancy