# vim colorscheme not apply clearly

Tags: vimrc, gvim, colorscheme

I apply colorscheme by writing in _vimrc file, but colors are working Partially.

I brought source code of colorscheme from [code-dark](https://github.com/tomasiser/vim-code-dark) using Plugin [Vundle](https://github.com/VundleVim/Vundle.vim).

For explanation, upload the pictures.
[image]
[image]
First picture is example of code dark, second picture is result of applying colorscheme to gvim in window.
As you can see, the colorscheme is working Partially.
And other all colorscheme code show this problem when I applying to gvim.

I guess the process have some discrepancy between open source and vim script language. But I can't understand code clearly...

Anyone have experience about this issue? Or any question seen before?

I'm really appreciate if you give any help. I wish your advice.

thank you for reading the question.

my _vimrc code

```
syntax on  
set encoding=utf-8  
set autowrite 
set autoindent 
set shiftwidth=4 
set smartindent
set nu " show line number
set incsearch 
set mouse=a 
set guifont=consolas:h11 

set nocompatible
filetype off 
set rtp+=~/.vim/bundle/Vundle.vim
call vundle#begin()

Plugin 'VundleVim/Vundle.vim'
Plugin 'vim-airline/vim-airline' 
Plugin 'vim-airline/vim-airline-themes'
Plugin 'airblade/vim-gitgutter'  
Plugin 'ctrlpvim/ctrlp.vim'    
Plugin 'hynek/vim-python-pep8-indent'  
Plugin 'nvie/vim-flake8'  

Plugin 'tomasiser/vim-code-dark'
" for colorscheme

call vundle#end()            
filetype plugin indent on  

colorscheme codedark

filetype plugin indent on               
let g:airline_powerline_fonts = 1
let g:airline_theme = 'codedark'
```

version

- vim _ window : 8.2

Comment: Why is this not the same as https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/31571/colorcheme-in-vim-is-partially-working-how-can-i-apply-the-theme-successfully ? Remember to use the [edit] button to update an existing question. I don't see any substantial difference besides the contents of your vimrc. You might want to follow [How to debug my vimrc](https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/2003/10604)

Comment: In your second example, the filename is `train.py`, so Vim will detect the filetype as `python`, but the code is in Ruby... Looks like the problem you're having is that you're getting Python syntax highlighting for your Ruby code. Could this be the problem?

Comment: thank you for your advice. I understand why problem is happening. Just `call <sid>hi()` more lass than Ruby that shown as examples. Thanks to you, I studied a lot.